# Phone number format and validation library

Tags: phone-number

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487906/java-phone-number-format-api) asking for a phone number format API in Java got me wondering why such an API doesn't seem to exist.  Given the number of [validation](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/package-summary.html#package_description) classes available under [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/), I would have thought such an API would be included.

My question is, does anyone know of a phone number formatting/validation library available in **any language** that could be used as a model for a small Java open source project?  Also, other than the large number of different phone number formats used throughout the world, does anyone know of any reason that such a project would be infeasible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Such an API in any language: [Number::Phone](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Number%3A%3APhone&mode=all) (example submodule: [Number::Phone::US](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/KENNEDYH/Number-Phone-US-1.5/lib/Number/Phone/US.pm)).

Data: the ITU's [National Numbering Plans](http://www.itu.int/oth/T0202.aspx?parent=T0202) index.

Comment: Crap, there are a lot of countries. :)

Comment: Thanks for the ITU link, even Qatar's data is current (this is rare).

Answer (score 27):

Google recently released [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) for parsing, formatting, storing and validating international phone numbers.

Comment: I use `libphonenumber` it takes over **3MB** ... that seems too much for me

Answer (score 3):

At http://www.geonames.org/ they have a database you can download, theres regEx rules for phone numbers included in the country info dataset.

http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

Look for the 'countryInfo.txt' file.

I suggest you build your own validator based upon that.

Comment: Wooops... Sorry, the RegEx is for postal-codes. It countains the country phone prefix though ie. +45 for Denmark

Answer (score 0):

Like it was said in the answers to the other question, no one's seen any for Java, and like you said, it would be nearly impossible due to the difference of phone number formats across the world.

And if you know the different formats for the regions that you're targeting, then it's usually pretty easy to implement it in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out Parsify Format here - https://www.mashape.com/parsify/format#endpoint-Phone-Number

It will return your number in several formats e.g.

{
  "e164": "+1234567890",
  "national": "234567890",
  "international": "+1 234567890",
  "valid": false,
  "type": "UNKNOWN"
}

You can get a more extensive response if it's a real number

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Answer (score -3):

**Phone Input field :**

```
<input class="left" id="field" name="field" />
```

**jquery Script:**

jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
   phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
   return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
   phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(([2-9]\d{2})|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
}, "Please specify a valid phone number");