# android Convert phone number in International Format

Tags: android, phone-number

I'd like to know whether it's possible to have phone numbers converted
into international format when a call is outgoing.

For instance, if a french user (sorry it's the only format i know i
won't make a mistake :-) try to call with the national format :
01.47.12.34.56 then a method will convert it into international format
like this : +33.1.47.12.34.56

I've looked into the doc of the PhoneNumberUtils but i don't know if
there is a method doing what i want.

Comment: I guess this would be a duplicate for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487906/java-phone-number-format-api and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501368/phone-number-format-and-validaton-library

Answer (score 6):

Old post, but if it helps anyone: use google's [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) library to do all sorts of formatting and validating for phone numbers. In this particular case, to convert to international format use the `format(PhoneNumber number, PhoneNumberFormat format)` api in class [`PhoneNumberUtil`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/googlecode/libphonenumber/libphonenumber/3.2/libphonenumber-3.2-javadoc.jar!/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil.html) in the same library.

Comment: Unfortunately `libphonenumber` only helps if you know the country code of the telephone number you give it. All the `PhoneNumberUtil` methods that manufacture a `PhoneNumber` from text require the number to start with a + and the country code (e.g. +447771234567) or must instead have the expected country code of the number specified. You'd think `libphonenumber` would be able to accept a phone number string in any format and attempt to identify the country code but this appears not to be the case.

Comment: @Phil, the app can access the SIM card location to get the country code.

Comment: @user908821 thanks for the very useful tip. Hadn't got around to investigating this yet, so you've just saved me a few hours!

Comment: @phil, you might be interested in this app that uses libphonenumber to do the formatting of contact lists [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=angel.twitch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=angel.twitch)

Comment: @AngelKoh That method is not always reliable as mentioned here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getNetworkCountryIso()

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the number come as a String?

Using Java's string methods you could do this yourself easily if I'm not mistaken?

So get the String, cop the 0 off and add the +33

Comment: but how can i retrieve the country code programatically ? (33 is only for france)

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to convert your local number to International Format, I am using google library https://github.com/google/libphonenumber as (Aswin Kumar) mentioned

Java

```
   public static String formatPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
    Phonenumber.PhoneNumber formattedNumber = null;
    String formatted = null;

    try {
        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) sContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String countryCode = manager.getNetworkCountryIso();
        formattedNumber = phoneUtil.parse(phoneNumber, countryCode.toUpperCase());
        formatted = phoneUtil.format(formattedNumber, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.E164);
        return formatted;
    } catch (NumberParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Kotlin

```
    private fun formatNumber(number: String?) {
    val phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance()
    var formattedNumber: PhoneNumber? = null
    var formatted: String? = null
    try {
        val manager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
        val networkCountryIso: String = manager.networkCountryIso
        Log.i("SERVICE " , "ISO "+ networkCountryIso)
        formattedNumber = phoneUtil.parse(number, networkCountryIso.toUpperCase())
        formatted = phoneUtil.format(formattedNumber, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.E164)
        Log.i("SERVICE " , "phone number"+ formatted)
        findCallerId(formatted)
    } catch (e: NumberParseException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```