# .NET Phone Number Parsing Library

Tags: .net, formatting, phone-number

Does anyone know of a generic phone number parsing library for .NET? Ideally I'm looking for something similiar to the Ruby [Phone](http://github.com/carr/phone) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with [Advanced Phone Number Type Implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/PhoneNumberStruct.aspx?display=Print) on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com).  At first glance, it seems that it may be lacking the internationalization pieces found in the Ruby library you referenced.

Of course, you could always start with an existing library and add on to it, and depending on the license of the original library, you might even choose to release your own that has exactly what you need.

Comment: Good find; this looks promising!

Comment: While this does seem like a good starting point, international number support is a likely requirement here; if anyone has any additional suggestions - I'd be very interested.

Comment: @DanP apparently you're not the only one looking to solve this problem.  Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501368/phone-number-format-and-validation-library .

Comment: @Ben: Yes, rather strange something doesn't exist for this...it would *seem* to be a pretty common requirement in a number of projects.

Comment: @DanP I think the problem you're going to face (and perhaps the reason the library likely doesn't already exist), is that phone-number parsing is a moving target, especially when it comes to internationalization.  You would think it would always be the same, but if you want to get really specific, there are lots of pesky little details for each country that could shift at whim.  If I were writing the library, I would start with a base template that could handle simple country codes and possibly expand to add validation for specific country codes that I anticipated using.

Comment: @BeN: agreed, I will accept this answer as the 'closest' one I've recieved; this should serve as a decent starting point - thanks for your feedback on this.

Answer (score 7):

I would go with the C# port of the Google libphonenumber library.

https://bitbucket.org/pmezard/libphonenumber-csharp/wiki/Home

Comment: Thanks for your answer; this looks very promising.

Comment: This port is no longer maintained. The site says: "2013-08-07 - THIS PORT IS NO LONGER MAINTAINED, FEEL FREE TO FORK THIS REPOSITORY AND KEEP UP WITH UPSTREAM UPDATES.". Also, the port has never been complete (but that might not be a problem if you're only using specific parts of it).

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend going with libphonenumber from Google, here's a [blog post on how to use libphonenumber](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/02/03/net-phone-number-validation-with-google-libphonenumber).

Parsing numbers is as easy as installing the [NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/libphonenumber-csharp) and then doing this:

```
var util = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
var number = util.Parse("555-555-5555", "US");
```

Comment: This port is no longer maintained. The site says: "2013-08-07 - THIS PORT IS NO LONGER MAINTAINED, FEEL FREE TO FORK THIS REPOSITORY AND KEEP UP WITH UPSTREAM UPDATES.". Also, the port has never been complete (but that might not be a problem if you're only using specific parts of it).

Comment: This port is currently being maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered taking the Ruby library you referenced and porting it to IronRuby, which runs on the .NET DLR?  I haven't used IronRuby before, but since it's a .NET language, you may be able to simply port the code over and expose and strongly-typed interface that can be better consumed in VB.NET or C#.

Comment: I had considered this option as well - just seems like a bit of an overkill for phone number parsing.

Answer (score 0):

There's [an alternative port of Google's libphonenumber on CodePlex](https://libphonenumber.codeplex.com/). It doesn't seem as popular as the other one, but it looks like it's based on a newer version of the library and it looks like it's still being developed.