# C# - Regex to validate all phone numbers?

Tags: c#, regex

I found the following Regex to validate all possible phone numbers, and tested it on [this Regex validator](http://www.regexr.com/):

```
^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?([-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*)?((\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{2,4})(?:[-.x ]*(\d+))?)\s*$
```

Why is it, then, when I use it in my code, it does not match the following number?

```
string text = "Herzeliya, Israel Tel: 972-52-2650599 Born 17/1/1975,";

List<string> Phones = new List<string>();

Regex phon1Regex = new Regex(@"^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?([-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*)?((\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{2,4})(?:[-.x ]*(\d+))?)\s*$"); 
MatchCollection phon1Matches = phon1Regex.Matches(text);

foreach (Match phon1Match in phon1Matches) 
    Phones.Add(phon1Match.Value);
```

The list `Phones` remains empty.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The anchors - remove `^` and `$`. See [the regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5c%2b%3f%28%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d%29%29%3f%28%5b-.+%28%5d*%28%5cd%7b3%7d%29%5b-.+%29%5d*%29%3f%28%28%5cd%7b3%7d%29%5b-.+%5d*%28%5cd%7b2%2c4%7d%29%28%3f%3a%5b-.x+%5d*%28%5cd%2b%29%29%3f%29&i=Herzeliya%2c+Israel+Tel%3a+972-52-2650599+Born+17%2f1%2f1975%2c).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Testing it now...

Comment: Thanks you @WiktorStribiżew. Would you like to post this as an answer?

Comment: Actually, I think the pattern needs pruning a bit. You are not using any captures from it, right? Besides, you most probably are not interested in extracting digits like `۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹`? `\d` matches them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What do you mean? Didn't get you there.

Comment: The `^` and `$` helped get precise matches. Now, I need more details - do you want to match anything in `11111111111972-52-26505994556666666`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The idea is to match any phone number. Examples: `(0055)(123)8575973` or `90191919908` or `+972052332332` or `052443443` or `052-4343-323` etc.

Comment: Yeah, that is why I think the last optional group is wrong: `-` and `.` should be taken out: `(?:[-.x ]*(\d+))?` => `(?:[x ]\d+)?`. The extension should only appear after space or `x`. Right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm so sorry but I'm having a hard time following you. I don't know what you mean by "extension", but if you just follow the above example I've provided - that is exactly what I need. And thanks for your help.

Comment: Before you start using it, see [that it matches more than you need](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5c%2b%3f%28%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d%29%29%3f%28%5b-.+%28%5d*%28%5cd%7b3%7d%29%5b-.+%29%5d*%29%3f%28%28%5cd%7b3%7d%29%5b-.+%5d*%28%5cd%7b2%2c4%7d%29%28%3f%3a%5b-.x+%5d*%28%5cd%2b%29%29%3f%29&i=11111111111972-52-26505994556666666%0d%0aExamples%3a+%280055%29%28123%298575973+or+90191919908+or+%2b972052332332+or+052443443+or+052-4343-323) and `(0055)(123)8575973` is not matched in full.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not just want to check if a Phone numbers String representation appears valid, but you want to find it in a much larger string. Those two operations are totally different and should thus be solved seperately. There just can not be a perfect "one fits all" regex Solution. If there is, Cultures failed at being uselessly distinct from one another and they realy do not like that ;)

Ideally you should not have all this Data in a single string. String is the 2nd hardest to Automate format (only raw binary is worse). Parsing those will be a pain. At the very least, those strings should have proper Comma seperation between segments or key/value pairs.
If you can modify the source to be more Automation Friendly, do that first. Even some XML output or proper CSV would be a huge step upwards.

Phone Number recognition is like any other Number recognition: The format is not fixed and indeed varries by culture as much as DateTime and other Numbers:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn454587.aspx
- [.NET Phone Number Parsing Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661620/net-phone-number-parsing-library)

Step 1 should be to split this large string into discrete string segments for:

- Place (Herzeliya, Israel); maybe City and Country as seperate fields
- Telephone Number (972-52-2650599)
- Date of Birth (17/1/1975)

Then you can *think* about parsing each of those strings, including the Telephone Number.