# Excel - search and replace various strings

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I have a table exported from Access database via SQL query. In excel, there are 3 columns: ID, name and a phone number... The problematic is a phone number column. Users have put in numbers in all kinds of ways so it looks very untidy and i cant use that field for other purposes.

Lets say that the default way that i want to see the numbers is: 385991234567. So it has the country code, than the area code, then the number... but all together combined.

In the database i have inputs like:

0991234567 - so without the country code

991234567 - without the country code and the leading zero of the area code

+385991234567 - with + in front of the country code

99/1234-567 - with various character separating the groups of numbers (i've managed to clean that up through the replace in the sql query).

The thing i want is to achieve the format i mentioned in the beginning. so add the country code, if needed remove the leading zero. The additional problem is that some of the numbers are 7 digits, others are 6 digits (without the country or area codes). Ive tried to do the replace by searching the 099 for instance, but if it occurs in the middle of the number, it gets changed too.

I dont know what to do. Or even is this the right section for this question (because i dont know if it is easier to do it in excel, via VBA macro, via sql query or something else). I cant do it by hand because its a field of approx. 100.000 phone numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501368/phone-number-format-and-validation-library (and good luck too!)

Comment: Garbage In, Garbage Out. Sorry, I couldn't help myself. :) Good luck!

Comment: I was thinking about it a bit... is it possible to combine REPLACE statement in an SQL query with LIKE statement? something like this: REPLACE(field, 'X', 'Y') WHERE X LIKE 'Z%'... i know that syntax is wrong but i was just giving a general idea/question... thanks

Comment: Are you storing the Country name in some other field, so that you can read the string from the right (stripping '-' etc) and then prepend based upon that Country name the appropriate country codes you want

Comment: It is too early to think about particular statements.  First you need a plan for how you will identify the action required for each number in the database.  Consider the four examples you give together with 1234567 (local number only).  How do you identify that 385 is a country code, 099 is an area code and that 1234567 is a local number?  I would start by fixing the data entry so new numbers are entered correctly.  Study the information in the link assylias has given you.  I add my wishes for good luck which you are going to need.

Comment: Questions, questions... Is the area code always 3 numbers long (incl. 0), is the tel. nr. always 7 numbers long? If the fist char is +, you can assume that the following nr is the Country Code (1 - 3 numers long). Can you work from the back? take last 7 as the tel. nr. and then process the remainder? If the first char is + or 00, can you match/verify the country codes against a lookup list, so you know where to split the country code/area code? etc. etc. And yes please put a validation check on new entries.

Comment: it is a cell phone database, so the area code IS always 3 numbers long (incl. 0). Tel nr. is sometimes 6 and sometimes 7 numbers long. If it is + at the begining, yes, i can assume it has the country code. The country code, if it is entered, is always for just one country...in this case Croatia, so 385. as for the area codes, there are a total of 7 area codes (or cell phone providers) with variations in writting, as i stated in the leading question. There are no new entries, its a final DB, so validation is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you all for help... in the end, i solved the problem through VBA macro in excel.

Comment: Yes, Peraklo submit your solution so all can benefit from your pain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so here it is... for starters, i used some SQL Queries to select the specific phone numbers and clean up the junk characters from phone numbers...

```
select sk, name1, phone into telefoni from 
(
SELECT customer_id as sk, name as NAME1, phone1 as phone from customers where len    (phone1)>7 and (phone1 like "09*" or phone1 like "3859*" or phone1 like "*3859*" or phone1 like "95*" or phone1 like "98*" or phone1 like "99*" or phone1 like "91*" or phone1 like "92*" or phone1 like "97*")
```

and this one...

```
SELECT distinct sk, name1, replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(phone, "/", ""), "-", ""), " ", ""), ".", ""), "*", "") as tel into telefoni2 from telefoni1 order by name1;
```

After that, i exported the data to excel and applied the next macro...

```
Sub test()
For Each cell In Selection
    If cell.Value Like "091*" Then cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "091", "38591", 1, 1, vbTextCompare)
    Next cell
End Sub
```

And thats about it... worked like a charm. The code may be messy or could be written better, but i am a novice, so i guess its ok :D