# Find & Replace Multiple data in excel

Tags: excel, replace, find

I have a excel file  containing 20,000 data. I need to remove about 1800 data from that file. I can do it one by one, find that data & delete them But this is quiet tough & lengthy process. Also I will have more task like this.

Is there any way in excel to match those data & delete them or put some mark on those cells or replace with defined data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736923/excel-search-and-replace-various-strings. Is that what you are looking for? Did you Google this?

Comment: This isn't really a programming issue, per se.  There are lots of tools (Pivot Tables, etc.) that would be useful to you, but it's unclear whether there are patterns in the data that you could use to sort them.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to add an if formula to mark the lines you want to delete by adding a value to a new column.

It would look something like this:

IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])

> =IF(A1>0,"delete","don't delete"[)](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/815-excel-remove-rows-based-on-cell-value.html#a1)

Than you may search and delete all the rows that have "delete" (or an unique identifier that you've selected in your formula) in that column. Check the link below on how you might do that.

[How to remove rows based on cell value in Excel?](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/815-excel-remove-rows-based-on-cell-value.html#a1)