# How to create JavaScript Regular Expressions for the validation of International telephone numbers with extensions

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, phone-number

I'm trying to match international phone numbers with extensions such as: +44 (123) 123 4567 ext. 123 and telephone numbers such as: +44 (123) 123 4567. When I type the extension it returns an invalid phone number. I also want to match US telephone numbers such as (212) 555-1212 and other telephone numbers, for example, +44 20 7893 4567. I am expecting user input using a prompt. My code is as follows:

```
function isValidTelephoneNumber(telephoneNumber){
    var telRegExp = /^(\+\d{1,3} ?)?(\(\d{1,5}\)|\d{1,5}) ?\d{3,4} ?\d{0,7}( (x|xtn|ext|extn|pax|pbx|extension)?\.? ?\d{2-5})?$/i;
    return telRegExp.test(telephoneNumber);
}

var phoneNumber = prompt("Please enter a phone number.", "");

if (isValidTelephoneNumber(phoneNumber)){
    alert("Valid Phone Number");
} else {
    alert("Invalid Phone Number");
}
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: This question means nothing. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you add the problem in the question and add some testing data about what should and should not match?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phone number format and validation library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501368/phone-number-format-and-validation-library)

Comment: How does my question look now? I hope I'm being clear as to what I am actually looking to do here.

Comment: @Mark - Hey Mark, I found your problem. The last section you have a syntax error `?\d{2-5}` should be `?\d{2,5}`

Comment: @ChaosPandion-The code works perfectly! Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

The last section you have a syntax error `?\d{2-5}` should be `?\d{2,5}`
I also recommend using `\s+` for your white space.