# How to distinguish Country code from contact number

Tags: android

I am able get the contact number from native contacts. I want to know the country code if the user already added in the number. Different country has different country code example for India it is +91. Some country codes are two digit some are three and so on.. So how to distinguish the country code from the contact number.

Thanks

Comment: go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487906/java-phone-number-format-api

Comment: @subspider, I feel both questions are different

Answer (score 2):

Try this: [Google's library for dealing with phone numbers](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/)

Comment: PhoneNumberUtil is not present in android 2.1 API

Comment: The library being opensource, you should try to have a look at how they extract the country code...