# how to set phone number in US format in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, phone-number

I am developing an application where I want to set phone numbers in the US format, like `xxx-xxx-xxxx`. How can I do this?

Comment: try this : [http://stackoverflow.com] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487906/java-phone-number-format-api)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to implement the following code then u will get " - " at entering number

```
    text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

         boolean flag = true;
         String eachBlock[] = text.getText().toString().split("-");
         for (int i = 0; i < eachBlock.length; i++) 
         {
             if (eachBlock[i].length() > 3)
             {
                 Log.v("11111111111111111111","cc"+flag + eachBlock[i].length());
             }
         }
         if (flag) {
             text.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

                 public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
                         keyDel = 1;
                     return false;
                 }
             });

             if (keyDel == 0) {

                 if (((text.getText().length() + 1) % 4) == 0) 
                 {
                     if (text.getText().toString().split("-").length <= 2) 
                     {
                         text.setText(text.getText() + "-");
                         text.setSelection(text.getText().length());
                     }
                 }
                 a = text.getText().toString();
             }
             else
              {
                 a = text.getText().toString();
                 keyDel = 0;
             }

         } else {
             text.setText(a);
         }

     }

     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) 
     {


     }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


    }


 });
```

Comment: @prasad.gai: Hi, your code working as it should be. But when user presses Delete button from the soft-keyboard, it behaves differently, i.e. '-' symbol is not appearing on the index on which it should come and comes on wrong places. What change should be done?

Comment: @prasad.gai hii i want to add in this foramt. (800) 555-6666  so plz tell me how is it posible? i just completed with u give code..

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change locale (Settings -> Locale and Text -> Select locale)

otherwise Hope this link will be helpful

http://androidforums.com/g1-support/39788-contact-numbers-us-format-uk.html

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/
Try this for dealing with phone numbers. It support formatting a national/international phone number, like you require.

Answer (score 0):

mobileEditText.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
The use the below function..

```
private final TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {


     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
         mAfter  =   after;
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!mFormatting) {
                mFormatting = true;
                if(mAfter!=0) // in case back space ain't clicked...
            PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(s,PhoneNumberUtils.getFormatTypeForLocale(Locale.US));                             
                 mFormatting = false;
            }
```