# android phone number invalid address

Tags: android, phone-number

In android phone if we enter the phone number as English alphabet (eg agchge) it says
invalid address.
If I enter English alphabet+some numbers(eg 232as55) it accepts.

Please let me know what are the rules to check the entered phone number
is acceptable by the android platform?.

Comment: check this link. it may be useful to you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487906/java-phone-number-format-api

Answer (score 1):

May be you regular expression is in another format which does not satisfies your requirement.

so try this

```
 String PHN_PATTERN = "^[+]?[-)(0-9]{3,20}$";
 String strphnvalue = resPhone.getText().toString();
 if(!(strphnvalue.equals("")))
 {
   if(!(strphnvalue.matches(PHN_PATTERN))) {               
      Toast.makeText(register.this,resource.getString(R.string.validphn), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
 }
```

`Note:=>`its give exact result. otherwise change this regular expression according to your requirement

Comment: My question is not related to the format of the phone number. But on how the android platform accepts and rejects the phone numbers.example it rejects "abcdef" and accepts "12abcd456"