# Android/Database. Any idea why disappears from phone number the first character, the "+"?

Tags: android, database

I used Log, when i get contacts number and there is everything right, until I read them from database and puts in a list, then I loose the "+"character from numbers.

```
public void getNumbers(String box) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/" + box);
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(c);

    // Read the sms data and store it in the list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
            SMSData sms = new SMSData();

sms.setNumber(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"))
                    .toString());

            String nr = sms.getNumber();
            Log.d("I got this:", nr);

            db.getSMSDataBySearch(nr);

            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    c.close();
}
```

And the SQLite code:

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO version3 (number) SELECT "+value+" WHERE NOT EXISTS "
                + "(SELECT 1 FROM version3 WHERE number = "+value+")", null);

Answer (score 0):

The SMS content provider does not store the formatting, only the numeric data.

If you want it formatted, there are tools or you can build it:

[Java phone number format API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487906/java-phone-number-format-api)

Comment: But in the Log appears with "+".

Comment: I don't know how you database is setup - but SQLite may not care if you have "+123456" for a number, it would just drop the "+". So is your DB storing it as a number?

Comment: It stores like a string. And if I use another method to write in database, that working. But with pasted code does not.