# Logical issue in list of numbers in the call log

Tags: java

My app gives a list of numbers in the call log.

Unfortunately, I encountered a small issue. My app lists the numbers below separately (even though they're the same number). Is there a way to group then into one number in my app? **I'd like to apply a method for numbers from ALL countries.**

*Example:*

754-3010    (Local)

(541) 754-3010 (Domestic)

+1-541-754-3010 (International)

1-541-754-3010 (Dialed in the US)

001-541-754-3010   (Dialed from Germany)

Code from my app:

```
Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery( CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null, null);

int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER );

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

     while ( managedCursor.moveToNext() ) {
            String phNumber = managedCursor.getString( number );
            list.add(phNumber);
}
```

I show the `list` in my app.

Comment: Yes, but you will need to provide much more context if you want help doing it.

Comment: I can only see one phone number Domestic - others are derived from it by adding different prefix.

Comment: @MaxZoom Exactly. The problem is that in my app these numbers show up separately (as if they were different). I only want to show ONE number. For example show `(541) 754-3010`

Comment: It seems that you need to filter lines without Domestic  word. But the code listed above does not allow to provide specific solution.

Comment: @bradimus I edited the question.

Comment: @MaxZoom I edited the question.

Comment: Is the text - (Domestic), etc next to the number also present in the list?

Comment: @Harshul No, it's not.

Answer (score 1):

**I am assuming all the numbers belong to USA**

You will need to convert all the numbers to a standard format in the list while iterating.

```
Set<String> numSet = new HashSet<String>();

while ( managedCursor.moveToNext() ) {
    String phNumber = managedCursor.getString( number );

    //Remove all non-numeric characters
    phNumber = phNumber.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");

    //Remove all leading 0s
    phNumber = phNumber.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");

    //Remove "1" from the number if size is 11
    phNumber = phNumber.length() == 11 ? phNumber.substring(1,phNumber.length());

    //Format the number
    phNumber = phNumber.replaceFirst("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d+)", "($1) $2-$3");

    //Check if set already has the number, else put
    if(numSet.get(phNumber) == null) numSet.put(phNumber);
}
```

---

**If your numbers are not limited to USA, you will need to write your logic to support other countries.**

Refer to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487906/java-phone-number-format-api)** post which has a similar requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately, I want code for numbers from *any* country (not just the USA). I apologize for not mentioning this in my question (now edited).

Comment: What you got here is enough to make it on your own. Give an upvote and try to do something on your own.

Comment: Is there a way to do it for numbers from any country @Harshul ?